# Pygame, keep jumping and glitching through the "ground"

Tags: python, pygame

My character won't jump properly, he keeps glitching through the ground. If i hold key up, my character won't stop going higher. Do you have some ideas for how I could fix it?

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
screen.fill((0,0,0))
pygame.display.set_caption('Jump and Run')

BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (250, 250,250)
RED = (250, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0,0,250)

direction = 'right'
way = 0
jump_high = 0

class Hero():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = pygame.image.load('hero.bmp')
        self.groundcontact = True
        self.vy = 0
        alive = True

    def check_pos(self):
        if self.y >= 400:
            self.groundcontact = True
        elif self.y <= 400:
            self.groundcontact = False

    def load_picture(self,surface):
        surface.blit(self.image,(self.x, self.y))

    def check_input(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x += 10
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= 10
        elif key[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.y -= 50

        if not self.groundcontact:
            self.vy += 1 #max(min(2,200), -200)
            #self.y += self.vy 
            print "not self.groundcontact"
        else:
            self.vy = 0
            #self.y += self.vy 
        self.y += self.vy


class Monster():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = pygame.image.load('monster.bmp')
        self.collision = False
        self.alive = True

    def load_picture(self,surface):
        surface.blit(self.image,(self.x, self.y))

    def walk(self):
       global direction
       global way
       if direction == "right":
          self.x += 4
          way += 1
          if way == 100:
              direction = "left"
       elif direction == "left":
          self.x -= 4
          way -= 1
          if way == 0:
             direction = "right"  

monster2 = Monster( 200, 333)
monster1 = Monster(400, 450)
hero = Hero(0, 400)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE,(0,500, 1200, 50))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()



    hero.check_pos()
    monster1.walk()
    monster2.walk()
    hero.check_input()
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    hero.load_picture(screen)
    monster1.load_picture(screen)
    monster2.load_picture(screen)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE,(0,500, 1200, 50))
    pygame.display.update() 


    clock.tick(40)
```

Comment: What is your problem, more specifically? This question isn't for people to wrote code for you, nor work out the logic or bugs.

Comment: It looks like the problem is that whenever the UP key is pressed, you run `self.y -= 50`. So if the player holds the UP key, the character keeps on rising. You probably want to keep some additional state that keeps track of if the character is in the air, and then only allow a jump to begin when the character is on the ground. Once the character is off the ground, you can ignore the player pressing the UP key. Finally when the jump begins, the action handler should then probably increase vy, rather than just y.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding my comment above, changing the Hero class to somthing like this:

```
JUMP_POWER = 10

class Hero():

    ...

    def check_input(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        ...

        elif key[pygame.K_UP]:
            if self.groundcontact:
                self.vy -= JUMP_SPEED
```